# rails 4 URI domain bad argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to write a simple validation to check if a user's domain name is valid. Here's the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'net/http'
  validate :domain_check

  def domain_check
    uri = URI(domain)

    request  = Net::HTTP.new uri.host
    response = request.request_head uri.path

    if response.code.to_i > 400
        errors.add(:domain, "This doesn't appear to be an valid site.")
    end
  end
end
```

This is based off the example in the Rails how to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods).

However this keeps throwing an error `bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)` about the line

```
uri = URI(domain)
```

I assume the `domain` variable is not getting to the function-- it seemed odd in the example in the Rails book that it didn't pass any variable, but the form vars are getting passed in correctly (I can see them in the debug info) and the form item `domain` is populated.

How do I pass in the `domain` var correctly so this custom validation method will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was (predictably I guess) strong parameters. I had to write a custom parameter sanitizer routine for Devise, so the form's domain could be accepted by the model.

More info on this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Answer (score 8):

You can change the function to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'net/http'
  validate :domain_check

  def domain_check
    uri = URI(domain)

    request = Net::HTTP.get_response uri

    if request.code.to_i > 400
      errors.add(:domain, "This doesn't appear to be an valid site.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: mmm, I misunderstood the question, is just that the error that I have when I do **response = request.request_head uri.path** throws me **ArgumentError: HTTP request path is empty** which is the _bad argument_ that he is getting

Comment: @robzdc-- thanks! giving an upvote since you fixed another issue. However, it appears the problem was strong parameters, so the vars were being submitted but then failing to get processed!